# Inline package overview documentation using roxygen

Tags: r, roxygen, helpfile

I imagine this is a simple thing that I keep overlooking in the documentation, but I can't seem to figure out how to get package-level documentation to work in R.  I'm not referring to function or class-specific documentation, but the documentation that you get when you type, for example, ?stats.

I've followed the general instructions I've found on the web, creating a sckeleton documentation file saved as .R.  The .R file is copied with the package scripts, but the help documentation doesn't get made into a .Rd file (unless I add a function definition also named after the package).

An example of what I've tried:

```
#'_PACKAGE
#'MyPackage
#'
#'MyPackage description
#'
#'MyPackage details
#'@alias{MyPackage}
#'@alias{MyPackage-package}
```

I'm having a hard time finding good examples of how to set up general package documentation, for some reason. I've written quite a few function help files, and I know my package help file is being found by roxygen, but it's unclear why I can't generate an .Rd from it.

Comment: You do need a `NULL` on the line following your documentation. [See here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-packages) for an example.

Comment: You may want to alter the title of your question.  This is not a 'overall package documentation'.  You know how to do this in a Rd file -- this is about a specific aspect of roxygen2.

Comment: @slickrickulicious Agreed. Try also `identical(NULL, {})` to see why both work equally well.

Comment: Updated title as well.  I was trying to avoid comments on how to document for functions rather than the package as a whole.

Comment: Edit of original comment:  Added curly braces around '\name' when I shouldn't have.  After removing, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer courtesy of @slickrickulicious in the comments above:

I needed to add NULL at the end of my documentation file and include '@name MyPackage'.  Doing so generated the package help file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I made my package (called `pkgName`) using devtools and already had a file named `pkgName_package.R` that was automatically generated. It contained the following lines:

```
#' @keywords internal
#' @aliases pkgName-package
"_PACKAGE"
```

After removing the first line, `@keywords internal`, and rebuilding, `pkgName-package` was a documented topic that appeared at the top of the reference manual.