# How do I use roxygen to document a R package that includes a function with the same name?

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

I'm learning to use roxygen. I see that the [rd vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html#documenting-packages) advocates using "_PACKAGE" to indicate that I'm creating package documentation, and says "This also works if there’s already a function called pkgname()."

I've also seen the [R packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-packages) approach of using

```
NULL
```

with @docType and @name specified, but when I attempt to make a toy example with either approach, it doesn't work as I expect.

As a toy example, I'd like to make a "hello" package that includes a "hello()" function.

I expect to get documentation about my hello **package** with

```
?hello
```

or perhaps something like

```
package?hello
```

and I expect to get documentation about the included hello **function** with

```
?hello()
```

Where am I going wrong? - implementation with roxygen, the way I'm attempting to query the documentation, incorrect expectations, or something else?

I've already looked at questions about [package documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439970/inline-package-overview-documentation-using-roxygen) and [function documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339021/devtools-roxygen-package-creation-and-rd-documentation/13348872#13348872), but things remain unclear to me.

Here's some details about my toy example:

hello/DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: hello
Type: Package
Title: A mostly empty package
Version: 0.1
Date: 2016-06-21
Authors@R: person("Some", "Person", email = "fake@madeup.org", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: MIT
LazyData: TRUE
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1.9000
```

hello/R/hello.R

```
#' hello
#'
#' This is a mostly empty package to learn roxygen documentation.
#'
#' Hello allows me to learn how to write documentation in comment blocks
#' co-located with code.
#' @docType package
#' @name hello
"_PACKAGE"

#' hello
#'
#' This function returns "Hello, world!".
#' @export
#' @examples
#' hello()

hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```

With this, after I run `document()`, hello/man/hello.Rd is generated. It contains a combination of the descriptions I've written for the hello package and the hello() function. `?hello` and `?hello()` both return that .Rd file.

Here's what the .Rd looks like:

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/hello.R
\docType{package}
\name{hello}
\alias{hello}
\alias{hello-package}
\title{hello}
\usage{
hello()
}
\description{
This is a mostly empty package to learn roxygen documentation.

This function returns "Hello, world!".
}
\details{
Hello allows me to learn how to write documentation in comment blocks
co-located with code.
}
\examples{
hello()
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

via @hadley, "don’t use @ name hello. That overrides default naming" and "sometimes you need to restart R because there’s something buggy with devtools and dev docs"

So, if I change my hello.R file to this:

```
#' hello
#'
#' This is a mostly empty package to learn roxygen documentation.
#'
#' Hello allows me to learn how to write documentation in comment blocks
#' co-located with code.
"_PACKAGE"

#' hello
#'
#' This function returns "Hello, world!".
#' @export
#' @examples
#' hello()

hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```

then `document()` makes hello-package.Rd and hello.Rd files. After I load `library(hello)`, then `package?hello` provides package documentation, and `?hello` provides function documentation, as I was shooting for!

Thank you once again, @hadley!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me now. I now get the \alias{package} that messes up linking.

Comment: I also have this problem coming back now.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Johan Larsson and brendan in comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37953308/5861244) it seems like the alias for the function is overwritten by the package.

A solution is mentioned [here](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/861) and [here](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/commit/2373703958af6b7f7f22d494aa3479431375bc82). It is to add `@aliases {pkgname}-package` (in this case `@aliases hello-package`).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it repeatedly said that you need to add `@aliases {pkgname}-package`, but it was not clear to me whether it was in the hello function comment block or in the package doc block.

Spoiler alert: it is in the package doc block:

```
#' hello
#'
#' This is a mostly empty package to learn roxygen documentation.
#'
#' Hello allows me to learn how to write documentation in comment blocks
#' co-located with code.
#' @aliases hello-package
"_PACKAGE"

#' hello
#'
#' This function returns "Hello, world!".
#' @export
#' @examples
#' hello()

hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```